# Calling nested http in route Resolver return Observable instead of data

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, angular-routing

I am trying to call nested HTTP call in resolve.ts. and implemented in the following way.

```
app.route.js:
    { 
     path: 'result/:start_date/:end_date', 
     component: ResultComponent,
     resolve:{hnData:ResultResolver}
    }
```

following is my resolver code

```
result.resolver.ts

   resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
   return this.service.firstHttp()
     .pipe(
      map((data)=>{

      param['data_from_firstHttp']= data.result;
      param['checkinDate']=route.paramMap.get('start_date');
      param['checkoutDate']=route.paramMap.get('end_date');

      return this.service.searchListing(param);


   })
 )
```

and the component code

```
result.component.ts

    { hnData : Observable}
```

Here in the component, I am expecting the result from serchListing service method instead I am getting observable.

Comment: http request return an observable as a response

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka Yes, I understand this. :), but how do I handle nested HTTP service calls in the resolver and get the result in the component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
firstHttp(): Observable<data1>;
searchListing(): Observable<data2>;

// you are trying to map:
map(Observable<data1>): Observable<Observable<data2>>
```

The question is - how to flatten it?

RxJs have a few ways:

1) Do we need to handle all events from each inner Observable?
`mergeMap/concatMap` - is the order of events important?

2) Can we skip some events from inner Observable?
`switchMap/exhaustMap` - is the new event have higher priority?

You can replace `map` on `mergeMap` to flatten Observable.

```
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
  return this.service.firstHttp()
    .pipe(
      mergeMap((data)=>{

        param['data_from_firstHttp']= data.result;
        param['checkinDate']=route.paramMap.get('start_date');
        param['checkoutDate']=route.paramMap.get('end_date');

        return this.service.searchListing(param);
  })
)
```

Comment: Sorry I am not expert in RxJs and also quite new to angular.
what I want to achieve through resolver is
1) get the data from the firstHttp()
2) pass the result of firstHtttp() to the searchListing() and the final result should be sent to the component.